# Creating form_for for model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, form-for

I have 2 models:

**brand**

```
has_many :products
```

**product**

```
belongs_to :brand
```

In my view (**show_brand.html.erb**), i displaying all information about brand using `@brand.name ...`.

I want to create form for **product** that belongs_to **brand** i'm displaying information about.

Something like:

```
form_for(@brand.products) ...
```

1. How can i preform that?
2. How can i attach `user_id` to **product** form (**product** `belongs_to` **user**) without adding it in controller manually

**NOTICE:**
  About first item in my list, i know that it can be done by upgrading routes to nested and passing array with main object and association object. But if there is another way of doing that? Without modifying **routes.rb** and ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

```
#brand_controller.rb

def new
  @brand = Brand.new
  @product = @brand.products.build
end

def create
  @brand = Brand.new(brand_params)
  if @brand.save
    .....
  else
   .....
  end
end

private

def brand_params
  params.require(:brand).permit(:id, brand_attribute_1, brand_attribute_2, products_attributes: [:id, :product_attribute_1, :user_id, :product_attribute_2])
end
```

In your form

```
<%= form_for @brand do |f| %>

----code for brand attributes ---

  <%= f.fields_for @product do |p| %>
  ----code for product attributes----  
  <%= p.hidden_field user_id, :value => current_user.id %> #to attach user_id to product
  <% end %>

<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I know about nested form, but i can't use fields_for because i'm not using form_for brand. i use form_for @product

Comment: @Src Update the post with your form code and controller code.

Comment: Ok, but now when i submitting form, it calls update method in brand controller (because form is in the **show** view and i'm using `@brand  = Brand.find(params[:id])` to display data in `brand/show` view),  and expects to update brand, not just create product. How can i deal with it?

Comment: Also, i'll try to validate another brand params, that are permited using strong_params and has validation on create, but i need just to create associated product, without touching brand.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, you can use "nested form".
Please check below link.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast

For question 2, even though you set user_id in "product form", you still have to do some check in your controller/model in case any undesired value is set to user_id. So the better way is you set it yourself at backend.